# Outlook calendar - see who has accepted a meeting without being the meeting organizer

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

In Outlook 2010 working against Exchange server, if I am the meeting organizer I have tracking options and at least one other way of seeing, if people have accepted or not.

However, when I am NOT the meeting organizer, I can't find any way to see, if other participants have accepted/rejected/etc.

Am I missing something, or is this by design?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's by design. See here:

**EDIT:** Original link was broken and I can't find an updated version of that page. Here's another that says the same thing:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/ewan/archive/2012/04/20/tip-o-the-week-110-tracking-outlook-responses.aspx

> If you're invited to someone else's meeting, you'll see options on how to respond, and you'll be able to look at the scheduling view to
>   see who else is on the list, but you won't be able to see how they're
>   responded to the invite (well not entirely). You may be able to see
>   the details in the scheduling view (depending on whether the invited
>   attendees have given you the permission to see their calendars).
>
> If you didn't organise the meeting, you may be able to open the calendar of the organiser and still be able to see who responded and how.

Answer (score 16):

I know this is an old thread about Outlook 2010, but it was the first search result addressing the same question for Outlook 2016. Informed guesses are as close as you can get if you're not the organizer and the calendars aren't shared.

If you open the occurrence you'll see the Scheduling Assistant button in the Meeting Occurrence tab.

[image: Scheduling Assistant]

It will show all the invitees and what you are allowed to see of their calendars. If their calendar is shared with you, you'll see their meetings. You'll just see colored and and patterned bars if their calendar is not shared. If there's no bar at the appointment time, you can be sure they have not accepted, but you can't know if they haven't responded or declined. Similarly, you can't know for sure if they're shown to be busy,  if they accepted this appointment or some other event.

Answer (score 10):

In Outlook 2010, click the Scheduling Assistant button on the Home tab; a list of invited people displays at left, along with their required/optional status.  But as stated above, you cannot get the response status unless you are the organizer (that is where the scheduling tab comes into play).

Answer (score 3):

If I want to see who is attending a meeting that I have not organised, I simply click on the relevant meeting in the calendar, then press the 'Respond' button in the top menu, then select 'Respond All'. This creates an email with all the attendees names in the 'To' box. Then just close the email. Clunky, I know, but it works for me. 8)

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can let them to know all response is to share your calender to them, so they will have a full access  and can track meetings responses 
Select calender tab

1. Find "Share Calender icon"
2. Enter all emails you want to be able to track
3. Check in " All receipents to view your calender
4. Change from " Avaibility only" to "Full details"

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that if you have Android smartphone, you can check the status of each attendee by clicking the appointment. I have not tested on iphone though.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an iPhone and your calendar is synchronized with Outlook, you will be able to see the list of invitees and if they're attending.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way using not Outlook, but Mail. If you go Mail's calendar, find the meeting and double click it, it will show you who's invited, and what their response is. You need to do it through the calendar and not through inbox. I haven't found any other way in Outlook 365.

Answer (score 0):

I was recently invited to a meeting that had been created using Outlook 2016 with the Teams plugin (I'm not sure if that makes a difference). Although I was not the meeting organizer, I was able to see if the other attendees had accepted by opening the meeting in:

- Outlook for Office 365 (although it seemed to take a while for the statuses to update)
- Microsoft Teams (this seemed to update much faster)

I was not able to see if the other attendees had accepted using the Outlook 2016 desktop client.

I haven't been able to find much official documentation for this; this was the closest I found:

> Meeting organizers have always been able to view which attendees have accepted, tentatively accepted, or declined a meeting invitation. Now, if the meeting was created by someone using Microsoft 365, all attendees who are using Microsoft 365 can also see the responses to the meeting invitation.

(Source: [Attendees can see others’ responses to a meeting invitation](https://support.microsoft.com/office/attendees-can-see-others-responses-to-a-meeting-invitation-f51437e5-352c-4223-b7d8-7020cd71f3c8))

Answer (score -1):

Want to know who else is invited? It may be considered rude to ask, but with Outlook you can look for yourself and no one will be the wiser. Open the meeting request and click the Scheduling tab. You'll see a list of all of the other people who were invited to the meeting. Note, however, that only the meeting organizer knows who is coming for sure. Why? Because only the meeting organizer receives the responses to the meeting request, and it's the responses that report back to the meeting organizer about who is coming.

Comment: I think the original question was about seeing whether people accepted or not. While you did answer it, I would try to reword your response to make the answer your main points. Then you can put your supplementary information after.